# Custom rewrite rule based on other custom post type title

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

I am trying to change url of one custom posts type based on name of the other one. To achieve this.

first custom post /test1/aaa

the other custom posts aftere rewrite

/test1/aaa/123

/test1/aaa/456

/test1/aaa/785

and so on.

These custom posts are connected with ACF Object field only.

So what I got so far and it almost works is

```
function apartments_list() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Mieszkanie', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Mieszkania', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Dodaj', 'kategoria' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Dodaj' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edytuj' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'Nowy element' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Wszystkie elementy' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'Zobacz element' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Szukaj' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'Brak elementów' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Elementy w koszu' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Mieszkania'
    );
    
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Mieszkania',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'=> true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        //'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-editor-kitchensink',
        'supports'      => array('title', 'page-attributes'),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug' => '/inwestycja/%mieszkanie_slug%'
            //'slug' => '/inwestycja/lofthaus-zablocie-test'
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'mieszkanie', $args );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'apartments_list' );


//Rewrite rule
function change_apartment_url( $url, $post ) {
    if ( 'mieszkanie' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $inwestycja = get_field('inwestycja');
        $inwestycjaObj = get_post($inwestycja);
        //$inwest_slug = 'lofthaus-zablocie-test';
        $inwest_slug = $inwestycjaObj->post_name;
        return str_replace('%mieszkanie_slug%', $inwest_slug, $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_apartment_url', 10, 2 );
```

and this for changing apartments name to id only

```
//Change apartment slug to post ID
function slug_save_post_callback( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    // allow 'publish', 'draft', 'future'
    if ($post->post_type == 'mieszkanie') {
            
        // only change slug when the post is created (both dates are equal)
        if ($post->post_date_gmt != $post->post_modified_gmt)
            return;

        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $post->id, $post_ID );
        
        //$new_slug .= '-' . $subtitle;
        if ($new_slug == $post->id)
            return; // already set
        
        // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 10, 3 );
        // update the post slug (WP handles unique post slug)
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_ID,
            'post_name' => $new_slug
        ));
        
        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 10, 3 );
        
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'slug_save_post_callback', 10, 3 );
```

So with that code the other customs post's url is being changed fine, while saving the post.
But then when I open that url, it redirects to the first custom post.

**Only when I change slug to fixed name and save perma links to clear rules, it works. But I need it to be dynamic. Any idea ?**

```
'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            //'slug' => '/investment/%mieszkanie_slug%'
            'slug' => '/investment/lofthouse'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

So after 2 days of searching I found a solution.

Permalink manager lite + this function and all works fine.

```
//Rewrite rule 
function pm_extra_permastructure_tags($default_uri, $native_slug, $post, $slug, $native_uri) {
  // Do not affect native URIs
  if($native_uri == true || empty($post->post_type) || $post->post_type !== 'mieszkanie') { return $default_uri; }

    $inwestycja = get_field('inwestycja', $post->ID);

    if( !empty($inwestycja) ) {
        $inwestycjaObj = get_post($inwestycja);
        
        $default_uri = str_replace('%mieszkanie_slug%', $inwestycjaObj->post_name, $default_uri);
    }
  
  return $default_uri;
}
add_filter('permalink_manager_filter_default_post_uri', 'pm_extra_permastructure_tags', 3, 5);
```